# Prove, that the only sets in $R^1$ which are both closed and open are $R^1$ and empty set(proof-check)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose there exists set $S$ in $R^1$. Then there exists another set $T = R^1 - S$.

Suppose $S$ is closed and open. It means:

- a)For all points in $S$ exists neighbourhood $N$, such that $N \subset S$.
- b)$S$ contains all its limit points.

If $S$ is open it means, that $S$ doesn't contain limit points of $T$(Sets are complements of each other). It means, that $T$ is closed. If $T$ is closed it means, that it contains all it limit points and there are no points outside set $T$. So we meet a contradiction.

Is this proof ok? If not, what should I improve?

Comment: As your proof makes no use whatsoever of any property of the topology of the real line, it cannot possibly be correct! (After all, there *are* topological spaces in which some, or all, sets are both open and closed!)

Comment: What is your contradiction? Could you make that clearer pls?

Comment: @Muno Because set T is closed( Set contains all its limit points and there are no points outside set T) and sets T and S are disjoint. Using this fact we conclude, that S cannot be closed. Contradiction.

Comment: There is no contradiction in your statement. $S$ is open $\iff$ $T=\mathbb{R}\setminus S$ is closed $\iff$ $T$ contains all of its limit points $\iff$ $S$ contains no limit points of $T$ ($S$ and $T$ are disjoint and their union is all of the ambient space).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider instead $\mathbb{Q}$ (with the relative topology from $\mathbb{R}$). The set $S=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:x^2<2\}$ is open, so its complement $T$ is closed. On the other hand
$$
T=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:x^2>2\}
$$
is open as well.

It follows that your attempt at a proof is wrong: if it worked, it would also apply to this situation, but it doesn't. You *must* use the specific property that makes the result true in $\mathbb{R}$, namely that every upper bounded set has a supremum.

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out, your proof is incorrect. I elaborate more on egreg's answer, in case you do not know how to make use of his hint. Let $S$ be a clopen set in $\mathbb R$ that is neither $\mathbb R$ or $\emptyset$, so we can pick an $x\in S$ and a $y\in S^c$ such that either $x<y$ or $y<x$. I will treat the first case, as the second follows symmetrically.

Fix $z=\sup\{s\in S:s<y\}$ (why does this supremum exist?). Now $z$ is either in $S$ or $S^c$ (we do not care), but by the definition of supremum it has to be a limit point for both (why?). However, we have assumed that $S$ is clopen, meanining that $S$ is closed and $S^c$ is closed, so $z\in S$ and $z\in S^c$ because both must contain all their limit points. This is obviously absurd, so our construction $S$ must be discarded.

As has been pointed out in the comments, it might not be entirely trivial to see why $z$ is a limit point of $S^c$, so I will outline that argument here:  Assume not. Then there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $[z,z+\varepsilon)\subset S$(why?). So $y\notin [z,z+\varepsilon)$, and certainly $y\not<z$, so $y> z+\varepsilon/2$, contradicting $z$ being an upper bound of the set $\{s\in S:s<y\}$.

Comment: It seems that the claim "$z$ is a limit point for $S^c$" is not immediately clear and needs a proof. From the definition of supremum, we can only find a sequence ${s_n}$ in $S$ such that $s_1\leq s_2\leq\ldots <y$ and $s_n\rightarrow z$. Hence $z$ is a limit point of $S$. But it is not clear why $z$ is also a limit point of $S^c$.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan I have outlined the argument for that case now. Hope it suffices.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually part of something way more general: Given any connected topological space $X$, the only closed-open sets are the $\emptyset, X$.

Comment: But is my idea correct? If yes, how can I use this idea to make it more specific?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't read it. I was just trying to give you some information about another subject that proves something a little more cleverly. In my attempt, I would just show that $(\mathbb{R}, | \cdot |)$ is connected.

Answer (score 0):

As Faraad Armwood's answer suggests, it turns out that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected. This, of course, requires proof. A more general version of this statement can be proven, however.

Some definitions:

A simply ordered set $L$ with at least one element is said to be a linear continuum if:

1) It satisfies the least upper bound property (whenever a subset $Y$ of a set $X$ ($X$ has the foregoing property) is bounded above, then the least upper bound of $Y$ is an element of $X$).

2) If $x < z$, then there is a $y$ so that $x < y < z$

> Theorem: If $L$ is a linear continuum in the order topology, then $L$ is connected.

The order topology is just the collection of all sets $\{x | a < x < b\}$

where $a, b \in L$ and $<$ is the order relation. The order topology is, for $\mathbb{R}$, exactly the open sets one is accustomed to in a first real analysis course.

If you would like to see a proof of this statement, I would consult Topology by Munkres (chapter 24) -- though I would also check out egreg's comment before resorting to it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ be a non-empty closed and open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. We go to prove that $U=\mathbb{R}$. Choose
$a\in U$. Define $A=\{x\mid[a,x)\subseteq U\}$. Since $a$ is an
interior point of $U$, $A$ is non-empty. We assert that $A$ is
unbounded. Prove by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that $A$
is bounded, then $\xi=\sup A<\infty$ exists. Choose a seuqnece $\{x_{n}\}$
in $A$ such that $x_{1}\leq x_{2}\leq\ldots$ and $x_{n}\rightarrow\xi$. Observe that $[a,\xi)=\cup_{n}[a,x_{n})\subseteq U$ and $U$ is closed, so we have $\xi\in U$. Choose $\delta>0$ such
that $(\xi-\delta,\xi+\delta)\subseteq U$, then $[a,\xi+\frac{\delta}{2})\subseteq U$
and hence $\xi+\frac{\delta}{2}\in A$. This contradicts to $\xi=\sup A$.

Clearly $A$ is unbounded $\Rightarrow$$[a,\infty)\subseteq U$.
We can prove similarly that $(-\infty,a]\subseteq U$. Q.E.D.